# What is the meaning of クイズ感覚 in this sentence?

Tags: words, sentence

> 「うん、あの、別に当てちゃうぞー？　みたいなクイズ感覚で聞いたわけじゃないですからね」

The definitions of 感覚 that I know doesn't seems to fit in クイズ and because of this I can't form a concrete meaning of this sentence at all.
For more context:

> とりあえず苦しいので胸倉を掴んできてる手は払って、と。
> 「借金取りってことは金を借りたんですよね？美琴さんが……のわけないか。ご家族でしょうか」
> 「正解！お父さんなの」
> 「うん、あの、別に当てちゃうぞー？みたいなクイズ感覚で聞いたわけじゃないですからね」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

クイズ[感覚]{かんかく}で here means something like “as if to play a quiz game”.

The word [正解]{せいかい} is often used when a contestant gives a right answer in a quiz show. Since the loan shark said it cheerfully when the character ventured to ask if it was a family member of Mikoto’s who owed him money, he commented he didn’t ask as if he were a quiz show contestant eager to hit the right answer.

When preceded by certain nouns, [感覚]{かんかく} carries a sense of “as if …” like that.

Here are a few examples with other similar expressions.

> [彼]{かれ}は[遊]{あそ}び[感覚]{かんかく}で[仕事]{しごと}をしている。
> [彼女]{かのじょ}とは[友達]{ともだち}[感覚]{かんかく}で[付]{つ}き[合]{あ}っている。